# Jsoup.parse(String) and document.toString() and document.html() not the same

Tags: java, jsoup

I need change some tag in html String so that I use Jsoup. Here I check but only convert and reverse:

The first I load String from url **=> str1**

Make Document from str1 to edit with jsoup:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str1)
```

Then I use function `doc.html()` or `doc.toString()` to convert doc to String **=> str2**

I load str1, str2 to **webview** by function loadDataWithBaseURL

And see that str2 not same when load str1 (example video frame not fit screen when use str2)

Why and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

JSoup [changes relative url's from the input to absolute url's on the output](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-document-from-string), using the base href you provide.

[org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(String)](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.lang.String-)

> Parse HTML into a Document. As no base URI is specified, absolute URL
>   detection relies on the HTML including a  tag.

You likely need to add the base href in your input content or call this method instead:

[org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(String content, String baseUri)](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)